Git global and in-repo configuration problem
In my PC, my git name and email is globally set to user1 and user1@email.com.
But in my specific git repo, I don't want to use that account. Instead i want to use another account. I used this command:
git config user.name user2; git config user.email "user2@email.com"

Then, When i used this command in my repository:
git config --list
It showed me more than one email and name!
user.name=user1
user.email=user1@email.com
init.defaultbranch=main
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/user2/repo.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.main.remote=origin
branch.main.merge=refs/heads/main
user.name=user2
user.email=user2@email.com

Stil after that, when I used the command git config user.name it showed me the SECOND user BUT I used the command git push, an error acured:
remote: Permission to user2/repo.git denied to user1.  
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user2/repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Why? I really don't know, i asked it several times from the ai and i still couldn't solve this problem...

Repository access permissions and credentials are completely different from the user name that you set as user.name and user.email. Look in your credential store how you access the repository.

Git's user and email have nothing to do with a GitHub account. They are only used to compose the Author field of commits to enforce accountability. Quoting an extract from page 3 of Version Control with Git:

Enforce accountability: One of the key aspects of a version control system is knowing who changed files, and if at all possible, why. Git enforces a change log on every commit that changes a file. [...]. Git ensures that changes will not happen mysteriously to files under version control because there is an accountability trail for all changes.

About Git user and email
It seems like that you have launched the commands git config --global user.name/email "value" multiple times with different values. Simply unsetting them with git config --global --unset user.name/email won't work, as Git will give you the following message warning: user.name/email has multiple values. You need to replace all of them with a single value, in order to have only one user.name and one user.email.
# replace all user.name configs with a single one containing "actual_name"
git config --global --replace-all user.name "actual_name"

# replace all user.email configs with a single one containing "actual_email"
git config --global --replace-all user.email "actual_email"

About GitHub access
To store your GitHub credentials, you need to set the credential.helper configuration to store.
git config --global credential.helper store

Then, install the cross-platform credential helper: Git Credentials Manager. Here is also a guide Caching your GitHub credentials in Git on GitHub, showing its configurations step by step. Also, remember to provide your personal access token instead of your password, as password-based authentication has been removed. For more info, read Why is Git always asking for my password? on GitHub.
